# How to get the Nth row from a table in Hive ? As there are no such function available in hive to get the rowid or row number?

Tags: hive

- ### How to get the Nth row from a table in Hive ? As there are no such function available in hive to get the rowid or row number?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query. It will work in latest versions where windowing functions are supported.

```
select * from 
(select row_number() over (partition by 1) rn, d.* from departments d) q 
where q.rn = 3;
```